# While Loop skipping scanf for it's condition.

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

I can't see why does the While loop just speed away and skipping the scanf for the char?
It would not even ask for my input and just loop like there's no tomorrow.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int number;
    int multiply, ans;
    char choice;

    printf("-------------------------------------");
    printf("\n      MULTIPLICATION TABLE           ");
    printf("\n-------------------------------------");


    do
    {

         printf("\nEnter an integer number:");
         scanf("%d", &number);


        printf("\nMultiplication of %d is :-\n", number);
        printf("\n");

        for(multiply=1; multiply<11; multiply++){
            ans = number * multiply;
            printf(" %d", ans);
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("\nWould you like to continue? [Y] for Yes,[N] for no : ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        printf("\n");

    } 
    while(choice='Y');

    printf("Thank You");
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf()` doesn't do what you think it does (newline characters, buffering, etc.). It's preferred to use `fgetc()`:

```
choice = fgetc(stdin);
```

For the same reason, you need to get rid of the trailing newline that

```
scanf("%d", &number");
```

leaves in the standard input buffer. To fix this, insert

```
fgetc(stdin);
```

after that particular call to `scanf()`.

Also, C is not Pascal. The equality comparison operator - and the condition - you're looking for is

```
while (choice == 'Y')
```

the single equation mark denotes an assignment.

Comment: @DCoder And fixing that doesn't fix the erroneous assumptions about `scanf()`.

Comment: Changed it but still skipping the input part.

Comment: @user1924648 what kind of insane input data are you using? Tried inserting another call to `fgetc()` after `scanf("%d", &number);`?

Comment: @user1924648 Yep, it does the trick, I just tried it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `==` operator for the comparison in `while` condition check as:

```
   while(choice=='Y');
```

Currently you are using `=` operator, which is assigning `Y` to `choice` variable.

Comment: I've fix that part but it still won't wait for me to put an input.

Comment: @user1924648 Use `fgetc()`, really.

Comment: Used fgetc() and now it's going out of the loop without waiting for me to enter anything.

It's working now, I just inserted an additional fgetc after getting the int.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time since I programmed in that language, but at a glance, you have:

```
while(choice='Y');
```

instead of:

```
while(choice=='Y');
```

== compares, = sets equal to.  So the while loop is actually not checking the condition you're trying to set.

Comment: "I've fix that part but it still won't wait for me to put an input. – user1924648 1 min ago"